# How to access EMP table in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I installed Oracle 12c on Windows Server 2008, installation went with no errors. After that I opened an SQL prompt, I don't see `EMP` nor `DEPT` tables (`EMP` and `DEPT` schemas should come by default, right?).

Could anyone can reply?

Comment: Did you choose to install the sample schemas?  If you did, `emp` and `dept` would be tables in the `scott` schema.

Comment: Have you looked at the container database or at the pluggable datebase? The samples are installed inside a pluggable database. See https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1

Answer (score 2):

When you create an Oracle database, either at the time the software is installed, or later using the DBCA utility, there is an option to install the Sample Schemas. This is de-selected by default - you must **explicitly** enable this at the time of database creation.

To install the sample schemas **after** the database is installed, got to ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema to find the schemas.

Note: the accounts will be locked and you will need to unlock them, for example [here](https://satendrakumar.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/how-to-unlock-sample-hr-database-in-oracle/).